# how to hide table header, and keep it hidden after insert/delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uiscrollview

I found out, that UITableView modify `contentSize` property and I can't set it by myself.

[image: Stack Trace]

This is my call stack. After this call `contentSize` is modified. I don't want it, because of that I want to hide header, so I need to scroll view a little bit down, and to make it I set `contentSize` little higher than visible to be able to scroll down a bit.

Any ideas how to hide table header, and keep it hidden after insertion/deletion ? By hide I mean table header initially "hidden" but show up when you scroll to the top.

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch data with CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like contentSize is modified by iOS private code just after controllerDidChangeContent is called.

Just for record. This is my solution (searchView is view that I want to hide):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    if (scrollView.contentSize.height <= scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.searchView.frame.size.height)];        
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, tableView.frame.size.height + self.searchView.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the tableview delegate methods for the size of header and return 0. it would like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0;
}
```

This would set the header for each section to be zero. You can also edit the footer size in the same fashion with `heightForFooterInSection:`

Comment: I know how to hide/show header by itself. Idea is to keep it "hidden" by default, I mean prevent to scroll to the top by default because on the top there is header view that should be visible only if user intentionally scroll to the top. I know how to scroll to hide it, but it show up after insert/delete operation because table change contentSize value by itself.